# Transparent Header overflown by main div

Tags: html, css, header, transparent, underflow

I have been looking for an answer to this question all over the interwebs, but I just can't find the answer.. I have a transparent header filled with a background image that is the same as my background, and I want my main div to scroll underneath it so the text is hidden. Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top">
    <!-- This is my header -->
    </div>
    <div class="main">
    [.....]
    </div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.top {
    background-image:url("http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/9215/headerqrk.png") no-repeat top center fixed;
    margin-top:0px;
    height:100px;
    width:1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    vertical-align:central;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:opx;
}

.main {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    bottom:20px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:990px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

I have made a jsFiddle which can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/qcaJJ/. Can you please help me out on how to get this working? Thanks in advance!

**ps.** Please don't mind the footer, I've used the footer from another page of mine, I don't want this one on this page :p

**pps.** If anyone knows a way to let the nav stay on it's place and the main2 div scroll, you're my hero! Kinda new to HTML and CSS..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using fixed position for the header, as the other answers pointed out, you're also using a background image with transparency, so when the main section scrolls underneath, you still see it. You need to add a background color like so, to make sure that the header div covers over what's scrolling underneath:

```
.top {
background: #fff url("http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/9215/headerqrk.png") no-repeat top center fixed;
```

Comment: YESSS!!! This is thè answer!! Thanks so much! I've set my width to 1920px (auto should be sufficient?) and background-color to #FFF and now my div scrolls underneath my header! You're my hero :D Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

**See my JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qcaJJ/3/**

You need a `fixed` position for your header rather than an absolute positioning for all the rest of your page.

```
.header{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}

.content{
    margin-top:100px;
    font-size:180%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `top` must be `position:fixed` for that to work. This ensures that it is always stuck at the top of the screen.

You may also want to set the `z-index` to something like `1000` so that it always stays on top of everything else.

Comment: I've added the fixed position and the z-index to the .top in CSS, but the text in the main div is still visible through the header (top)..
Is there any way you can show me a jsfiddle on how my html/css should look? I can't figure it out :s